# Can I use SignalR 3 or AJAX to stop timeout for long file downloads

Tags: ajax, signalr

I have an ajax POST that sends a CSV file to the server. I have signalR 3 working to inform the client as to where its up to with the 16000 odd records its processing via a progress bar. It works.... for small files with processing finishing in less than two minutes. Any time processing takes longer it times out.

I have looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21926555/how-to-use-signalr-events-to-keep-connection-alive-in-the-right-way) and its not what I require.. and

I have tried adding an extended timeout using ".timeout: 600000" on the POST but that doesnt work. It still times out at 2 minutes but processing works and the database is still updated and it even tries to send back those records that were new.

Can I use a SignalR server call to keep the session alive? (how, with SignalR 3)?

can I use AJAX?

I need it to wait just over 8 minutes to avoid timeout.

AJAX code:

```
    //On button click POST file and signalR connection Id back to controller.
    $('#SubmitFile').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // <------------------ stop default behaviour of button
        var url = "/SuburbsAndPostcodesAdmin/FileIndexView";
        var connId = $.connection.hub.id;
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('File', $("#txtFileUpload")[0].files[0]);
        fd.append('connId', connId);
        //Post back the file with the SignalR Id.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (result) {
                //display the results in a partial view.
                $("#DisplayResults").html(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            },
        });
    });
```

SignalR client code:

```
        // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
    var progress = $.connection.progressHub;

    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        connectionId = $.connection.hub.id;
        $("#SubmitFile").removeAttr("disabled");
        $("#initialise").html("<h4>" + "Ready to upload" + "</h4>" + "<br /> " + "<br />");
    });
```

updating progress bar:

```
        //Send from server to the client process current notification.
    progress.client.notifyProgress = function (processedRecords, newRecords, percentage) {
        $("#NoOfRecordsProcessedValue").text(processedRecords);
        $("#NoOfNewRecordsFoundValue").text(newRecords);
        $('.progress-bar')
              .css('width', percentage + '%')
              .attr('aria-valuenow', percentage);
        if (percentage > 5) {
            $("#workDone").text(percentage + "%");
        }
    };
```

Comment: You tried to increase the connectionTimeout ?  `GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(110);`.The `notifyProgress` message is sent every   120sec when you have big CSV files ?